# Use Custom Error in Nodejs with async

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async.js

I am using async in a Nodejs application to run a series of functions in series. Each function calls the callback with an err (Can be null) and a result.

What I want to do is check in the series callback for a particular error ... a custom error:

```
async.series({
  one: function(callback){
       // Doing Stuff
       if(No good)
         callback(new error('Custom Error'), 'Failure');
       else
         callback(null, 1); 
  },
  two: function(callback){
      // Doing Stuff
      if(No good)
         callback(new error('Custom Error 2'), 'Failure');
      else
         callback(null, 2);
  }
},
  function(err, results) {
   if(err) {
     // Test for which error was thrown above 
   }
});
```

Any ideas on creating custom error and then testing for them in this context would be great.

Comment: use uppercase `new Error('Custom message')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a custom error class:

```
var util    = require('util');
var MyError = function (msg) {
  MyError.super_.apply(this, arguments);
};
util.inherits(MyError, Error);
// use it in your callback
callback(new MyError(), ...);
// check for it
if (err instanceof MyError) {
  ... 
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping it was something I could do on the fly rather than using the utils inheritance. Something like new Error({type: MyError)); ... and then test for an instanceof in the callback. oh well.

Comment: You don't really have to use `util.inherits`, `var MyError = function(){};` will work as well if you want to test with `instanceof`.